# Add a column to a data.table with less rows than the column length

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

Basically, I want to write the following `dplyr` code using `data.table`:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(a = 2:3)
(df2 <- group_by(df, a) %>%
  do({b <- runif(as.numeric(.[1, 1]))
      data.frame(b, c = rep(sum(b), nrow(.)))}))
```

With `data.table`, the `by` argument collapses the results to a single row per group and I can not figure out how to avoid this argument in a succinct code.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(a = 2:3)
(dt[ , b := runif(as.numeric(.SD[1, 1])), by = a])
(dt[ , c := sum(b), by = a])
```

Comment: `dt[, { b=runif(a); list(b=b, c=sum(b)) }, by=a]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list() in the second argument within the square brackets.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(a = 2:3)
(dt <- dt[ , list(b = runif(as.numeric(a))), by = a])
(dt[ , c := sum(b), by = a])
```